# Ionic cors issues

Tags: angularjs, authentication, ionic-framework

I am trying to do authentication in ionic with laravel in the backend. When I was testing it with postman authentication works, and I am getting back a token, but I have cors issues when I am trying to do authentication form ionic, when I do ionic serve. I have tried to set it up as suggested [here](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/).

This is my ionic.project file:

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "app_id": "",
  "gulpStartupTasks": [
    "sass",
    "watch"
  ],
  "watchPatterns": [
    "www/**/*",
    "!www/lib/**/*"
  ],
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api/*",
      "proxyUrl": "http://myBackend.app/api"
    }
  ]
}
```

My gulpfile:

```
var replace = require('replace');
var replaceFiles = ['./www/js/app.js'];

gulp.task('add-proxy', function() {
  return replace({
    regex: "http://myBackend.app/api",
    replacement: "http://localhost:8100/api",
    paths: replaceFiles,
    recursive: false,
    silent: false,
  });
});

gulp.task('remove-proxy', function() {
  return replace({
    regex: "http://localhost:8100/api",
    replacement: "http://myBackend.app/api",
    paths: replaceFiles,
    recursive: false,
    silent: false,
  });
});
```

So when I try to authenticate user, on a failed attempt I get a return from my backend:

> POST http://myBackend.app/api/authenticate 401 (Unauthorized)

And when I send the right credentials I get:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/api/authenticate.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Comment: I think you need to replace `http://myBackend.app/api` with `http://localhost:8000/api/authenticate`.

Comment: you allow access controll in cors https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en check this and add this to your chrome and 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Comment: it was my stupid mistake I was copy pasting and had a localhost address in my controller, when I fixed that it was working